# Replacing Components in SketchUP in other angle

Tags: replace, sketchup

I am training myself currently in Sketch Up, so this might be a trivial question. I get a SketchUp file from another program and want to replace, the components inn that file with my components. However the new component should be placed in another angle. As example I want to replace the component of a roof with the component of a house. If the angle stays the same the house is in an angle as the roof and not flat on the floor.

As example I want to replace the component of a roof with the component of a house. If the angle stays the same the house is in an angle as the roof and not flat on the floor.